# Redmine - Project Version causing Error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've installed a fresh copy of Redmine on an Ubuntu box for a plugin development project.  Once I got the basic Redmine install up and running and ran the migrations, everything seemed to work fine.  However, anytime I get to a page which requires use of the Version class, an error is thrown.

It seems as though it may be trying to use a different Version class -- perhaps the one that specifies the Version of redmine?

UPDATE: It seems that any references to `Version` in Redmine are calling a constant called `Version` and not the class `Version`.

For example, creating a Project works.  However, when I try to view the Project, I get this:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 167ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `joins' for "3.1.7.3":String):
    42:     <% end %>
    43:
    44:     <h1><%= page_header_title %></h1>
    45:
    46:     <% if display_main_menu?(@project) %>
    47:     <div id="main-menu">
    48:         <%= render_main_menu(@project) %>
  app/models/project.rb:455:in `shared_versions'
  lib/redmine.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:446:in `call'
  lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:446:in `allowed?'
  lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:164:in `block in menu_items_for'
  lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:163:in `each'
  lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:163:in `menu_items_for'
  lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:90:in `render_menu'
  lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:80:in `render_main_menu'
  app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:45:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb___3256852209764588002_58036380'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:153:in `show'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (28.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (44.9ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used a Puphpet installation (which provided RVM( and that seemed to be the problem.  I fixed it by doing a pretty spare Vagrant box setup and installed RVM manually afterward.

And for the record, the `Version` constant it was looking for was part of the Ruby core libs, specifically in `rexml`